# CoffeeScript Class and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript file in which I am writing a class for interactions with an audio player but for some reason I can't get it to play nicely inside of another coffeeScript file in my Rails app.

player.coffee:

```
window.Player = ->
    constructor: (@player_id = "player") ->
        jw = {
                'flashplayer':"<%= asset_path('player.swf') %>"
                'controlbar': 'top'
                'autostart': 'false'
                'width':'400'
                'height':'49'
                'playlist': '[]'
                'skin':"<%= asset_path('awardfm.zip') %>"
                'dock':'false'
                'wmode':'transparent'
            }
        jwplayer(@player_id).setup(jw);

    play: (track_data) ->
        console.log track_data
```

player_interactions.coffee

```
$ ->
    jw = window.Player "player" || {}
    $('.play').click ->
        jw.play('test')
```

<del>I keep getting this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Player is not defined`</del>

**Its now working with the above code samples**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make a class globally addressable you should prefix the name of the class with "@" (unless you are within a closure in which case you need to prefix it with "window." but you probably wouldn't want to do that anyway).

player.coffee

```
class @Player
    constructor: (@player = "player") ->
        ...

    play: (track_data) ->
        ...
```

player_interactions.coffee

```
jw = new Player
```

Answer (score 2):

To access a function from one coffeescript file in another, attach the function in the top level window object then reference it in your file, `window.MyClass`